# How can I find $\sum_{k=1}^{1233}f(\frac{k}{1234})$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $$f(x)=\frac{e^{2x-1}}{1+e^{2x-1}}$$ 
>   Then find $$\sum_{k=1}^{1233}f\left(\frac{k}{1234}\right)$$

How I proceed: $$\sum_{k=1}^{1233}f\left(\frac{k}{1234}\right)=\int_{1}^{1233}\frac{e^{\frac{2x}{1234}-1}}{1+e^{\frac{2x}{1234}-1}}~dx$$ then how I solve this integral. please help.

Comment: Why should the sum be equal to the integral

Comment: Amr is spot on. You are looking at this in a wrong way.

Comment: Then how I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:

\begin{align}
f(k/1234)+f((1234-k)/1234)=&
\frac{e^{\frac{k}{617}-1}}{e^{\frac{k}{617}-1}+1}+\frac{e^{\frac{1234-k}{617}-1}}{e^{\frac{1234-k}{617}-1}+1}&=&\\
=&\frac{e^{k/617}}{e^{k/617}+e}+\frac{e}{e^{k/617}+e}&=&1
\end{align}

So your sum is equal to $616+f(1/2)$.

Comment: This is nice +1

Comment: Really it is good.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks to Mathematica for simplifying the terms, I wouldn't have voluntarily done this.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$

Put $x=\frac k{1234}\implies  f\left(\frac k{1234}\right)+ f\left(\frac {1234-k}{1234}\right)=1$

Then put $k=1,2,,\cdots ,\frac{1234}2=617$

so $ f\left(\frac 1{1234}\right)+ f\left(\frac {1234-1}{1234}\right)=1,$

$ f\left(\frac 2{1234}\right)+ f\left(\frac {1234-2}{1234}\right)=1,$

**

$ f\left(\frac {617}{1234}\right)+ f\left(\frac {1234-617}{1234}\right)=1\implies  f\left(\frac 12\right)=\frac12$

Adding we get,
 $\sum_{k=1}^{1233}f\left(\frac{k}{1234}\right)=617(1)-f\left(\frac {617}{1234}\right)=617-\frac12$

Comment: Thank you for giving me complete answer.

Comment: @Argha, thanks for putting up a nice problem.

Comment: I got this problem and stuck. So I put it. But thank you for the comment.

Comment: @Argha, welcome.

Comment: I like how you can solve for $f(1/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a closed form for your sum exists. However, we note that:

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(\frac{k}{N})=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Thus, for large values of $N$ you can estimate the sum using the integral.

To evaluate the integral, we note that $\frac{d}{dx}[e^{2x-1}+1]=2e^{2x-1}$, thus:
$$\int_0^1\frac{e^{2x-1}}{e^{2x-1}+1}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{2e^{2x-1}}{e^{2x-1}+1}dx=[\frac{1}{2}\log(1+e^{2x-1})]_{x=0}^{x=1}$$

Comment: Yes I will add it

Comment: The value of the integral ?

Comment: @Argha See akkkk's answer,way better than mine